# fetch Cert subject name and Cert Expiry date for Microsoft azure subscription

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to fetch Cert subject name and Cert Expiry date for a given windows azure subscription, i am unable to fetch the expiry date using get-azurecertificate, kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the data property contains the base64 formatted data of the certificate. If you export this field to a cer file, it is a certificate.
Here is the screenshot of my lab:

[image: GUI]

To decode it directly in Powershell, please try the following commands:

```
$certlist = Get-AzureCertificate -ServiceName stlcs01
$data = $certlist[0].Data
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
$cert | fl *
```

I've tested it in my lab, it works for me.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Powershell]